# Cannot Display exact adress on the map (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, map, google-map

[image]
 I seem unable to display exact adress of an account shipping adress on a google map!

```
 import { LightningElement, api,track ,wire} from 'lwc';
 import getRecentModifiedAccounts from 
  "@salesforce/apex/AccountListController.getRecentModifiedAccounts"
 import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
 import STREET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ShippingStreet';
 import CITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ShippingCity';
 import POSTCODE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ShippingState';

 export default class viewAccount extends LightningElement {
  // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
 @api recordId;
 @api objectApiName;
 @track error;
 wiredJobsResult;
@track mapMarkers=[];   
@wire(getRecord, {
    fields: [ STREET_FIELD, CITY_FIELD, POSTCODE_FIELD]
},getRecentModifiedAccounts)
fetchAcc({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.mapMarkers = [
            {
                location: {

                    Street: data.fields.ShippingStreet.value,
                    City: data.fields.ShippingCity.value,
                    State: data.fields.ShippingState.value ,                            
                },


          }
      ];
      console.log('this.mapMarkers => ', JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));
  } else if (error) {
      console.error('ERROR => ', error);
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
 <lightning-output-field
            field-name="ShippingAddress"   id="ad" variant="label-hidden" 
        ></lightning-output-field> </br>
         <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">

            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-4">
                <lightning-map  map-markers={mapMarkers}  
        zoom-level="10"
        list-view="hidden"></lightning-map>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Apex :

```
    public with sharing class AccountListController {

   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static list<Account> getRecentModifiedAccounts(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, OwnerId, Owner.Name, 
   AccountSource,  
             AnnualRevenue, Type, Industry, Phone,
            BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, 
    BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry,
            ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, 
     ShippingPostalCode,ShippingCountry, ShippingAddress,

            Website
            FROM Account 
            Order By LastModifiedDate desc 
            limit 50];
}
```

}

Comment: Can you confirm and debug the value for `ShippingAddress`. May I suggest to use `getFieldValue` to get values from the getRecord bound object, like this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record

Comment: I didn't understand exactly

Comment: it didn't work !

Comment: what does your apex class look like?

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely some odd behavior going on with the map component and I find the auto wiring sometimes just makes things more confusing.

I got it to work by changing the component code to this:

```
import { LightningElement, api,track} from 'lwc';
```

import getRecentModifiedAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/AccountListController.getRecentModifiedAccounts"

export default class viewAccount extends LightningElement {

```
// Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
@api recordId;
@api objectApiName;
@track error;
wiredJobsResult;
@track mapMarkers;   


constructor() {
    super();
    getRecentModifiedAccounts().then(records => {
        try {
            this.mapMarkers = [];
            for(let i=0; i<records.length; ++i) {
                if(records[i].ShippingStreet && records[i].ShippingCity && records[i].ShippingState) {
                    this.mapMarkers.push({
                        location: {
                            Street: records[i].ShippingStreet,
                            City: records[i].ShippingCity,
                            State: records[i].ShippingState                         
                        }, 
                        value: records[i].Id
                    });
                }

            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }

    });
}
```

}

And then changing the html markup to

```
<template>
<lightning-output-field field-name="ShippingAddress"   id="ad" variant="label-hidden" ></lightning-output-field></br>
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1"></div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-4">
        <template if:true={mapMarkers}>
            <lightning-map  map-markers={mapMarkers}  zoom-level="5" list-view="hidden"></lightning-map>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

The lightning-map component behaves strangely since it isn't updating the map-markers property even though the controller has mapMarkers set to track. If I leave it undefined and only render it once it's defined by the constructor using

```
<template if:true={mapMarkers}>
```

it renders it with the right values. It's almost like it's copying the initial values internally and then caching them and not updating them when they're updated in the parent component.